# Where to find STREAM_ANALYTICS_TOKEN for installing Winds?

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to install [Winds](https://github.com/GetStream/Winds) on my computer but there is one value for configuration that I can not find on dashboard but it says that is required for [.env](https://github.com/GetStream/Winds/blob/master/.env_example) STREAM_ANALYTICS_TOKEN

in [readme](https://github.com/GetStream/Winds/blob/master/README.md) it says that this value is required but there is no clue where I can get it. where it can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pro organizations, your `STREAM_ANALYTICS_TOKEN` can be found in the "Analytics" section of your app in the Stream dashboard.

However, I *believe* that Winds should still function normally without it. Are you getting an error when trying to start or use the app?